# Can someone explain how sizing works for windows forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

[image]

An explanation relative to this format would be nice, I've been looking for a simple explanation; however, nothing really explains in a simplistic way without making me have to read pages of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object will have a position (Left, right...).
The margin is the space between your object and another object.
The padding is the space between the internal objects inside your parent container-object...
and the blue zone is the place where are your children object.